# How to make mapping for any mark

Tags: key-bindings, mark

I want to make a mapping that jumps to the file of a mark but on the last visited line. Ideally I would write something like this:

```
nnoremap z<mark> '<mark>`"
```

Where `z` is some command prefix and `<mark>` is the mark I want to use. However I don't see any way to implement this for all marks. I could manually expand this but that is nasty.

```
nnoremap zA 'A`"
nnoremap zB 'B`"
nnoremap zC 'C`"
" ...
```

I was wondering if there is anything nicer then iterating over all marks.

Bonus points if the command can be `za` and the mark is automatically upper-cased.

Comment: What's the '`A'`" for? marking A and then `nnoremap zA` '``A works . Doesn't work for ` ``ma of course. Sorry formatting in comments is horrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function MyJumps()
    let chr=nr2char(getchar())
    if chr < 'A' || chr > 'Z'
        return ""
    endif
    return "'" . chr . '`"'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> z MyJumps()
```

This maps `z` to call the function `MyJump()`. This functions first gets
one char of input. If the input is not in the range `A-Z` it returns an empty string.
Else it returns `` '<char>`" ``.

As the `nnoremap` is a map-expression, Vim takes the returned characters and executes them.

See `:help map-expr`

Comment: Thanks. I have provided full code based on yours here: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1835053